# pip install fbprophet in centos 7 - error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: linux, centos, python, pip

I tried to install fbprophet for Python 3.6 using `pip install fbprophet` in CentOS 7, but I am getting

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

How would I fix this? I tried installing the Python development headers using `yum install python-devel` and `yum install python36u-devel`, but nothing happened.

Comment: You need to install or reinstall `gcc`.

Comment: I tried But not working

Comment: What's not working? Did the `gcc` installation fail? What does `where gcc` show?

Comment: gcc installed good, yum install gcc -y and yum install gcc-c++ -y, everything installed good. gcc --version also showing .. but we are getting the same error

Comment: An error return 1 (`EPERM`) strictly means a permission error (eg execute bit not set on program or trying to compile modules to a write-protected directory), but it is also used as a general failure code, so I'm not sure you can rely on its strict meaning. Do you need to run`pip` with root permissions?

Comment: You can check `gcc` permissions with `ls -l $(which gcc)`: it should have `r` and `x` for owner, group and other users. You may need to follow one or more symbolic links and make sure all have the required permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, we have upgraded latest version gcc in centos7, then it is working

Comment: Glad it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

I updated latest version gcc from gcc 4 to gcc 8.99, its working

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by installing the following packages over CentOS (not all may be required):

```
yum -y install centos-release-scl
yum -y install httpd httpd-tools rh-python38-python-mod_wsgi.x86_64 devtoolset-8-gcc devtoolset-8-gcc-c++ gcc gcc-c++  rh-python38-python rh-python38-python-devel unixODBC-devel libaio

./usr/bin/python3 /etc/get-pip.py

pip install -r /etc/pip-req.txt

/usr/local/bin/install-fb.sh
```

- Contents of **pip-req.txt**

> ```
> absl-py==1.3.0
> abydos==0.5.0
> altair==4.2.0
> argon2-cffi==21.3.0
> argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
> arviz==0.13.0
> asttokens==2.0.5
> astunparse==1.6.3
> attrs==21.4.0
> backcall==0.2.0
> backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
> beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
> bleach==5.0.0
> blinker==1.4
> blis==0.7.9
> cachetools==5.0.0
> catalogue==2.0.8
> certifi==2021.10.8
> cffi==1.15.0
> cftime==1.6.2
> charset-normalizer==2.0.12
> click==8.0.4
> cmdstanpy==0.9.5
> colorama==0.4.6
> confection==0.0.3
> contourpy==1.0.6
> convertdate==2.4.0
> cx-Oracle==8.3.0
> cycler==0.11.0
> cymem==2.0.7
> Cython==0.29.32
> debugpy==1.6.0
> decorator==5.1.1
> defusedxml==0.7.1
> deprecation==2.1.0
> entrypoints==0.4
> ephem==4.1.3
> executing==0.8.3
> fastjsonschema==2.15.3
> Flask==2.1.2
> flatbuffers==22.10.26
> fonttools==4.38.0
> fuzzywuzzy==0.18.0
> gast==0.4.0
> geographiclib==1.52
> geopy==2.2.0
> gitdb==4.0.9
> GitPython==3.1.27
> google-auth==2.14.0
> google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
> google-pasta==0.2.0
> greenlet==2.0.0.post0
> grpcio==1.50.0
> gunicorn==20.1.0
> h5py==3.7.0
> hijri-converter==2.2.4
> hmni==0.1.8
> holidays==0.16
> idna==3.3
> importlib-metadata==5.0.0
> importlib-resources==5.7.1
> ipykernel==6.13.0
> ipython==8.3.0
> ipython-genutils==0.2.0
> ipywidgets==7.7.0
> itsdangerous==2.1.2
> jedi==0.18.1
> Jinja2==3.1.2
> joblib==1.1.0
> jsonpickle==2.2.0
> jsonschema==4.5.1
> jupyter-client==7.3.1
> jupyter-core==4.10.0
> jupyterlab-pygments==0.2.2
> jupyterlab-widgets==1.1.0
> keras==2.10.0
> Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
> kiwisolver==1.4.4
> korean-lunar-calendar==0.3.1
> langcodes==3.3.0
> libclang==14.0.6
> LunarCalendar==0.0.9
> Markdown==3.4.1
> MarkupSafe==2.1.1
> matplotlib==3.6.2
> matplotlib-inline==0.1.3
> mistune==0.8.4
> mod-wsgi==4.6.8
> munkres==1.1.4
> murmurhash==1.0.9
> nbclient==0.6.3
> nbconvert==6.5.0
> nbformat==5.4.0
> nest-asyncio==1.5.5
> netCDF4==1.6.1
> networkx==2.8.7
> notebook==6.4.11
> numpy==1.23.4
> oauthlib==3.2.2
> opt-einsum==3.3.0
> packaging==21.3
> pandas==1.5.1
> pandocfilters==1.5.0
> parso==0.8.3
> pathy==0.6.2
> patsy==0.5.2
> pexpect==4.8.0
> pickleshare==0.7.5
> Pillow==9.3.0
> plotly==5.8.0
> ply==3.11
> pmdarima==1.8.5
> preshed==3.0.8
> prometheus-client==0.14.1
> prompt-toolkit==3.0.29
> protobuf==3.19.6
> psutil==5.9.0
> ptyprocess==0.7.0
> pure-eval==0.2.2
> pyarrow==8.0.0
> pyasn1==0.4.8
> pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
> pycparser==2.21
> pydantic==1.9.2
> pydeck==0.7.1
> Pygments==2.12.0
> PyMeeus==0.5.11
> Pympler==1.0.1
> pyodbc==4.0.34
> pyparsing==3.0.9
> PyQt5==5.15.4
> PyQt5-Qt5==5.15.2
> PyQt5-sip==12.11.0
> pyrsistent==0.18.1
> pystan==2.19.1.1
> python-dateutil==2.8.2
> pytz==2022.6
> pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0
> pyvis==0.2.0
> pyzmq==22.3.0
> requests==2.27.1
> requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
> rsa==4.9
> scikit-learn==1.1.0
> scipy==1.9.3
> seaborn==0.11.2
> semver==2.13.0
> Send2Trash==1.8.0
> setuptools-git==1.2
> sip==6.7.4
> six==1.16.0
> smart-open==5.2.1
> smmap==5.0.0
> soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
> spacy==3.4.1
> spacy-legacy==3.0.10
> spacy-loggers==1.0.3
> SQLAlchemy==1.4.41
> srsly==2.4.5
> stack-data==0.2.0
> statsmodels==0.13.2
> tenacity==8.0.1
> tensorboard==2.10.1
> tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1
> tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.1
> tensorflow==2.10.0
> tensorflow-estimator==2.10.0
> tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.27.0
> termcolor==2.1.0
> terminado==0.13.3
> thinc==8.1.5
> threadpoolctl==3.1.0
> tinycss2==1.1.1
> toml==0.10.2
> toolz==0.11.2
> tornado==6.2
> tqdm==4.64.1
> traitlets==5.2.0
> typer==0.4.2
> typing_extensions==4.4.0
> tzdata==2022.1
> tzlocal==4.2
> ujson==5.5.0
> unicodedata2==15.0.0
> Unidecode==1.3.6
> urllib3==1.26.9
> validators==0.19.0
> waitress==2.1.1
> wasabi==0.10.1
> watchdog==2.1.7
> wcwidth==0.2.5
> webencodings==0.5.1
> Werkzeug==2.1.2
> widgetsnbextension==3.6.0
> wincertstore==0.2
> wrapt==1.14.1
> xarray==2022.11.0
> xarray-einstats==0.3.0
> xgboost==1.6.2
> zipp==3.10.0
> ```

Contents of **install-fb.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
source /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/enable
pip install pystan==2.19.1.1 fbprophet==0.7.1
```